# Function to find the second largest key in a symbol table

Tags: java, linked-list, key-value, symbol-table

so im writing a function that will find the second largest key in an un-ordered symbol table using a linked list implementation, the code I have so far isnt working right and was wondering if someone had any tips thanks!

```
public Key secondLargestKey () {
          if(first == null) return null;
          if(size()<=1)  return null;
          Node secondMax=null;
          Node Max=first;
           for (Node pointer=first.next;pointer.next!=null;pointer=pointer.next) {
              if(Max.key.compareTo(pointer.key)<=0) {
                 secondMax=Max;
                 Max=pointer.next; 
               }
              else {
                 secondMax=Max.next;
                 Max=pointer; 
              }

              }   
            return Max.key;
        }`
```

Output:

```
secondLargestKeyTest: Correct  String  Answer: null
secondLargestKeyTest: Correct  String A Answer: null
secondLargestKeyTest: *Error*  String AB Expected A Actual: B
secondLargestKeyTest: Correct  String ABC Actual: B
secondLargestKeyTest: Correct  String ABABABC Actual: B
secondLargestKeyTest: *Error*  String ZAYBXC Expected Y Actual: Z
```

Comment: When `pointer`  is larger than `Max`,   previous `Max` becomes `secondMax` and `pointer` becomes new `Max`; `Max.next` and  `pointer.next`  are of no consequence. And at the end of it all, `secondMax` is the desired result.

Comment: thanks for the reply, is this what you mean with max becoming second max and pointer becoming new max?   if(Max.key.compareTo(pointer.key)<=0) {
     secondMax=Max;
        Max=pointer; 
         }
     else {
                  
                  Max=secondMax; 
                  pointer=Max;
               }
     }   
      return secondMax.key;
  }

Comment: I led you slightly astray, it's a little more complicated.   If `pointer.key` > `secondMax.key` AND also `pointer.key` > `Max.key`, then `secondMax` becomes old `Max` and `Max` becomes `pointer`; but if if `pointer.key` >  `secondMax` only, `secondMax` becomes `pointer` and `Max` stays the same.

Comment: when I use this code i am getting a null pointer exception  if(first == null) return null;
    if(size()<=1)  return null;
    Node secondMax=null;
    Node Max=first;
     for (Node pointer=first.next;pointer.next!=null;pointer=pointer.next) {
      if(pointer.key.compareTo(secondMax.key)>0 && pointer.key.compareTo(Max.key)>0) {  
     secondMax=Max;
        Max=pointer; 
         }
     else if(pointer.key.compareTo(secondMax.key)>0) {
              secondMax=pointer; 
     }
     }     
      return secondMax.key;
  }

Comment: Well, in order for the algorithm to work, you can't avoid starting off with at least `secondMax == null` so your code needs to be prepared to deal with that.  For example, instead of just `if (secondMax.key.compareTo(pointer.key) <= 0)...`, you'd write `if (secondMax==null || secondMax.key.compareTo(pointer.key) <= 0)...`

Comment: great thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close to being correct. The terminating condition in your `for` loop needs to check that `pointer!=null`, not `pointer.next!=null`. Also, if `pointer.key` is less than `Max`, you then need to compare it to `secondMax`, and accept it if it's greater, or `secondMax` is `null` (i.e. not yet set)

Here's some code for reference:

```
static <E extends Comparable<E>> E secondMax(Node<E> head)
{
  if(head == null) return null;

  E max2 = null;
  E max1 = head.key;
  for(Node<E> curr=head.next; curr!=null; curr=curr.next)
  {
    if(curr.key.compareTo(max1) >= 0)
    {
      max2 = max1;
      max1 = curr.key;
    }
    else if(max2 == null || curr.key.compareTo(max2) > 0)
    {
      max2 = curr.key;
    }
  }
  return max2;
}

static class Node<E>
{
  E key;
  Node<E> next;
  public Node(E k)
  {
    key = k;
  }
}
```